# Select record table mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a small search engine project and I need some help with a SQL query. My table looks like this (example):

```
user_id  |       group_id
---------------------------
1        |        2
2        |        2
2        |        3
3        |        2
```

I would like to look for : `user_id` who has `group_id = 2` and `3`
So a possible result would be:

```
user_id   |       group_id
---------------------------
2         |        2
2         |        3
```

How should the select query look like?

Comment: Do you want all rows for such user IDs or just the group id 2 and 3 rows?

Comment: I just want to get user_id with both group_id = 2 and equal to 3, that is, the same user_id

Comment: @KiềuToàn check my answer below and test. ignore the downvoter for i have understood your question

Comment: Thank you for giving me the great idea OmariVictorOmosa

Comment: "I just want to get user_id with both group_id = 2 and equal to 3, that is, the same user_id"  yes, you said that.  that identifies which user ids you want to include in the results.  I was then asking which group_ids you want to include: only 2 and 3 (so exactly two rows for each user id) or all rows for those user ids (so if they had a 2, 3, and 4, show three rows for that user id)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM your_table
 WHERE user_id IN (
         SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
                    FROM your_table
                   WHERE group_id IN (2,3)
                GROUP BY user_id
                  HAVING COUNT(user_id) > 1 )
```

Check [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=6612acb9fd925f33c9b0276d2dc2890a).

---

**EDIT.** I have modified my answer to below to be more accurate as pointed out by @ysth:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, 
                group_id
           FROM usergroups
          WHERE user_id IN (
                  SELECT DISTINCT user_id 
                             FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user_id, 
                                                   group_id 
                                              FROM usergroups ) g
                            WHERE group_id IN (2,3)
                         GROUP BY user_id
                           HAVING COUNT(user_id) > 1 )
```

Check [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=026c144f38c1ad5ef6a63d82fae6a301).

Comment: this only works if there can't be duplicates of the same user+group (but it wasn't my downvote)

Comment: @ysth if there are duplicates that would depend on whether he wants to show duplicate result , if he does not want he can do distinct query in the outer query [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=758cb753154e74634bef19e2b8345b7e) . But that is not part of the question asked

Comment: if there are duplicate group_id=2 records, that user_id will be counted even with no 3's.  a distinct in the outer query doesn't fix that, you would need to modify the count() condition

Comment: @ysth i get you, let me update to [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=026c144f38c1ad5ef6a63d82fae6a301)

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose your table name is `users` and we will select only two columns `user_id` and `group_id` from the users table

```
SELECT user_id, group_id FROM users WHERE group_id IN (2, 3);
```

Comment: I just want to get user_id with both group_id = 2 and equal to 3, that is, the same user_id

Comment: what if you have records like user_id = 3 and group_id = 2 and 3 ?

Comment: What I want to find is the duplicate user id with groups 2 and 3 like the question above which I illustrated